# Wildcard SQL Query - Narrowing Search Results

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am making a wildcard search query on the Wordpress database for "Post Title".

My results would vary:

- "Post Title - 1"
- "Post Title 2"
- "Post Title #3"
- "After the Post Title 1"
- "Before the Post Title 1"
- "After the Post Title 2"
- "Before the Post Title 2"

I would like to limit my wildcard results to:

- "Post Title - 1"
- "Post Title 2"
- "Post Title #3"

Any idea or algorithm I can achieve this?

---

Code

```
$query = "SELECT ID, `post_title` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_title` LIKE '%".$titleRequest."%'";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: Post your code so we may be able to answer your question.

Comment: I added code but it needs an algorithm to sort the results.

Comment: Why would it need to sort the results? Your question is about limiting the result set. If it does not need sorting, please remove the `algorithm` tag - I don't think it has anything to do with these.

Comment: I meant to "sort out" and thus limiting the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT ID, `post_title` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_title` LIKE '".$titleRequest."%'";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

The initial `%` means "match anything here" - but you do not want to do that, you want to match only things that start with the title requested. The second `%` is ok - you do want to match things after Post Title, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the `WHERE` clause within your `SQL` Query:

```
WHERE FieldName LIKE 'Post Title%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement **fuzzy logic** in your search. But its a very complex algorithm, fortunately there are already some plugins that have implimented this algorithm like "[Relevanssi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/)". Once installed it will override your current search mechanism and add its own, then you can modify it accordingly.